# Page View not showing on path'd page

Tags: views, 6, path-aliases

I'm using Drupal 6 and I'm pretty sure I'm using Views 3. I created a page called All Events (alias: all-events) and created a view that displays as a page. Under Page Settings for the path option I put all-events.

My problem is that I can see the view results in the preview, but whenever I go to the all-events page it is blank save for the title and the one tag I put on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first created a node whose path is all-events and then created a page view whose path is all-events then the page and the view are competing of the same alias. Just delete your node and your view should display fine.

Comment: So I don't need to create a page for the view, that will be generated automatically? But I guess if it was a block view then I would have to create a page to put the block on. I think I'm understanding this.

Comment: Typically you would assign a block to a sidebar or some other region.